# Scraping the average daily sales from a graph

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, bots

The average daily sales are part of a graph which is why I am struggling to scrape the data. If there is a way to scrape the data from the graph(mainly the sales per day) help would be much appreciated.

```
 link='https://waxpeer.com/karambit-gamma-doppler-factory-new/item/21733106690'
```

I am using selenium for most of my code however I do not mind using other methods.

```
time.sleep(20)
linkos = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//* 
[@id="main_layout"]/section/div/div[2]/div[1]/h3')
for sales in linkos:
print(sales)
```

the xpath only contains data that looks like 'd=M0,0 L6.965,0 a0,0 0 0 1 0,0 L6.965,42.6 a0,0 0 0 1 -0,0 L0,42.6 a0,0 0 0 1 -0,-0 L0,0 a0,0 0 0 1 0,-0 Z'

Would I have to find what data is = to specific values for each day and then find the mean?

If you need to see the rest of the code I can send but I do not want to crowd post.

Comment: It is possible, but really very complex for Selenium only solution.  
I guess it can be done with beautiful soup

Comment: Post your code...

Comment: I dont mind using bs4 and I will post the current code with some extra information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That data comes from an API POST request you can mimic

```
import requests

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'}
data = '{"name":"\u2605 Karambit | Gamma Doppler (Factory New)"}'
r = requests.post('https://waxpeer.com/api/get-sales-history', headers=headers, data=data.encode('utf-8'))
r.json()
```

You could also write as:

```
import requests

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'}
data = {"name":"★ Karambit | Gamma Doppler (Factory New)"}
r = requests.post('https://waxpeer.com/api/get-sales-history', headers=headers, json=data)
r.json()
```

Not sure if you meant to then average the averages returned e.g.

```
import requests
from numpy import mean

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'}
data = {"name":"★ Karambit | Gamma Doppler (Factory New)"}
r = requests.post('https://waxpeer.com/api/get-sales-history', headers=headers, json=data)
history = r.json()
print(f"For data in data range: {' - '.join([history['data'][i]['day'].split('T')[0] for i in range(0, -2, -1)])}" \
       " mean was {:,.2f}".format(mean([i['avg'] for i in history['data']])))
```

Comment: say w was to implement this code for several pieces of data could i replace "★ Karambit | Gamma Doppler (Factory New)" with a variable?

Comment: That sounds likely. Give it a try and see.

Comment: It does work, thanks for your help. would i just do print(r.json())['count'] to get the count?

Comment: `[i['count'] for i in history['data']]` for indiv counts and for number of days/data points `len(history['data'])`

Comment: You are an absolute legend. Can I buy you a pint or coffee or something. You've actually made my day.